# What was Captain Marvel supposed to do once she reached her destination?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the end battle of *Avengers: Endgame*, while Steve wanted the Stones as far away as possible, Bruce/Hulk urges for them to be returned to their original timeline after his conversation with the Ancient One. 
So Hawkeye, Black Panther, Spider-Man and ultimately Captain Marvel try to get the gauntlet to the quantum tunnel in the van.

What was she supposed to do once she reached the van? Neither did she have pym-particles to shrink to sub-atomic-level and traverse the quantum realm (also no GPS, but that might be less of a problem for Captain Marvel?), nor did she have any idea where and when the stones were taken.
Was she supposed to deliver it to Scott? From the speed of her approach this seems unlikely and Scott was also aware only of the three Infinity Stones in NY.

Is there any official word on what Captain Marvel wanted to accomplish?

Comment: Scott and Hope was already at the Van and they had the necessary equipments to do the needful. Everyone else tried to bring stones to the Van

Comment: Captain Marvel the Fourth maybe should have just snapped her fingers......if Hulk and Thanos and Tony can do it.......Would have made getting to the van easier.

Comment: Honestly, she should've just flown straight up, dropped the gauntlet on the Moon, then flown back down to provide cover for Scarlet Witch as she dismantled Thanos.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The plan was to get the Infinity Stones to Scott who would then take them through the tunnel, this is made somewhat clear during the initial "plan".

> **"Steve:** Get it started. We'll get the stones to you.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Scott presumably knew of more than just the Infinity Stones in New York because he was present when they came up with the plan. It makes sense that everyone knew of them all in case the plan went south so they could take control if needed. The only odd case is Cap and Tony who went back further but I think we can infer either they told people off screen or they would have said it before Scot went through to make sure they had the plan sorted.

Comment: From the scene moments before Thanos blew up the van it seemed like she was going for it at full speed and didn't intent to give the gauntlet to Scott.

Comment: @Scorch91 She was going full speed to try and get to the van, it's not 100% clear if she was trying to go through the tunnel or give the Stones to Scott but considering the "plan" it seems more likely to be the latter.

Comment: [Scene for reference](https://youtu.be/BpaNee0JeGI?t=1628). Given the fact that Thanos was just meters away, it's highly unlikely that Captain Marvel would have had time to pass the gauntlet on, even more though at the speed she was going. [The scene of the "plan"](https://youtu.be/BpaNee0JeGI?t=1201). The plan and the action coming don't really match. This shows that nobody except Hulk knew that the stones needed to go back to their time

Comment: @Scorch91 Regardless of speed she can always slow down and stop...

Comment: @Scorch91, also she could have intended to move the van to a better location.

Comment: Plus, the #1 goal at that moment was to keep the stones away from Thanos, so send them back a week and then deal with sending them further back later.

Comment: They also had to make these choices in the spur of the moment, so it's not like they were making the most well-thought out ones - getting Gauntlet back would have still left Mjolnir in the wrong time etc. After all, even if they do something imperfectly, they have some ability to fix things further now that Hank Pym is back. The main thing was to avoid a re-snap, then they had leeway to be more methodical.